# How To Customize Event Display in FullCalendar V4 in Angular

Tags: events, fullcalendar, angular7, customization

I'd like to customize what the events display in fullCalendar. Currently they only display the Title but I would like to know how to display additional fields of the event. Using FC-v4  angular 7 version.

Comment: This kind of thing gets asked very frequently. eventRender is your friend. In that callback you can manipulate the HTML of the event however you wish,  based on the event object data. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<full-calendar #calendar defaultView="dayGridMonth" style="background: white; padding: 5px" timeZone="UTC"
                (eventClick)="openTaskView($event)" (dateClick)="openDateView($event)" aspectRatio="1.8"
                [customButtons]="options.customButtons" [header]="{
                    center: 'title',
                    left: 'filter,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
                    right: 'prev, next today'
                }" [plugins]="calendarPlugins" [events]="selectedEvents" (eventRender)="calendarEventRender($event)" [selectable]="true"
                schedulerLicenseKey="GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source">
            </full-calendar>
```

comp.ts

```
calendarEventRender(info){
      if(info.event.extendedProps.batchId)
        info.el.text = " "+info.event.title+ " - "+ info.event.extendedProps.batch.name;
    }
```